# Expanding a know result about Lindelöf spaces to, say, compact or locally compact spaces?

Tags: general-topology

> **Known result 1:** If a topological space $X$ can be represented as a countable union of Lindelöf subspaces, then $X$ is Lindelöf.

My question is, can this result be rewritten (*Mutatis mutandis*) with respect to, say, compactness or local compactness? Possibly even with respect to the separation axioms.

> **Claim:** If a topological space $X$ can be represented as a finite union of countably compact subspaces, then $X$ is countably compact.

*Proof:* Let $X:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}X_n$, where all spaces $X_n$, $1\leq n\leq k$, are countably compact. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a countable open cover of $X$. Then $\mathscr{U}$ is a countable open cover of $X_n$ for all $1\leq n\leq k$. So, for each $1\leq n\leq k$ there exists $\mathscr{U}_n$, a finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$ ,covering $X_n$. Then
$$\mathscr{U}_{\infty}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}\mathscr{U}_n$$

is a finite (as a finite union of finite sets) subcollection of $\mathscr{U}$ covering $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactness has a straightforward analog:
If $X$ is a *finite* union of compact subspaces, then $X$ is compact.

For locally compact, countable unions are definitely out, as $\Bbb Q$ shows.

For finite unions, consider $A=\{(x,\sin(\frac1x)): x > 0\}$, which is locally compact (homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$) and $B = \{(0,0)\}$ which is even compact, but $A \cup B$ is not locally compact, as the origin has no compact neighbourhoods.
So few seems possible there as well.

Comment: Nice examples. I've just thought about countably compact...I have a feeling it would work?

Comment: @D.Math a *finite* union of countably compact spaces is countably compact, yes. The proof is obvious.

Comment: Well, I'm *somewhat* new to these definitions. As such, proofs are aren't all that obvious. I wrote up a proof for the claim that "a *finite* union of countably compact spaces is countably compact". Can you check it?

Comment: @D.Math it’s fine.